# What user executes the code when running SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriveleges?

Tags: development, security, asp.net

I have done research on this and still can't find a strong answer. Some soures say that when using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriveleges that the code is executed as a site collection admin. Some sources say, SHAREPOINT\system. Some sources say the application pool identity running the code. Some sources say, simply, with "higher priveleges".

I have an ASP.NET web app that is using server side code (C# with the SharePoint.Microsoft.dll) to interact with SharePoint. My code is currently running under the service account that is running my application pool. There are certain times that I would like to elevate such that the user running the code has site colletion-level access, but would like to know exactly which user runs the code when using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriveleges.

Answer (score 2):

With 99% certainity, it is the app pool identity that is used when RWEP is used in code.

Confirmed with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

> Parameters 
>   secureCode
>   Type:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated
>
> A delegate method that is to run with elevated rights. This method
>   runs under the Application Pool identity, which has site collection
>   administrator privileges on all site collections hosted by that
>   application pool.